# to get hourly and six hours based weather from NOAA

Tags: php, json, curl, noaa

I am  trying to get the weather data from NOAA and parse it to get the current temperature, humidity, and other values. I am trying to get the JSON data from its website, which uses the latitude, and longitude values to get the weather data of location. I am getting trouble to get the data, and I found out we have to use CURl to get it done, and I have no idea on using CURL.

this is the URL i am using to get the data

"https://api.weather.gov/points/$latitude,$longitude/forecast".

This is what I tried, based on one example I found here. I want to know how to pass the latitude, and longitude, and add the forecast at the end in the url

```
<?php
/**
 * Created by PhpStorm.
 */


$url='https://api.weather.gov/points/'; //noaa url of choice
$params=array('39.7456','-97.0892','forecast');
$curl = curl_init();
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_FAILONERROR, true);
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION, true);
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, $params);
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_URL, $url);
$result = curl_exec($curl);
$data = json_decode($result);
curl_close($curl);
echo "<pre>";
echo json_encode($data, JSON_PRETTY_PRINT);
echo "<pre>";
?>
```

Comment: If you look at the example URL, you should inject the latitude and longitude in the actual URL, not as header parameters. Remove the CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER row and just use this URL: `https://api.weather.gov/points/39.7456,-97.0892/forecast`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Simply append the coordinates to the URL.

```php
<?php
$ch = curl_init('https://api.weather.gov/points/39.7456,-97.0892/forecast');
curl_setopt_array($ch, [
    CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER => true,
    CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION => true,
    CURLOPT_SSLVERSION => 6,
    CURLOPT_USERAGENT => 'Firefox',
]);
$response = curl_exec($ch);
if($response === false)
    exit(curl_error($ch));
print_r(json_decode($response));
```

A few notes about the code :

- Passing the URL to `curl_init` is the same as setting it with `curl_setopt(CURLOPT_URL`
- `curl_exec` returns `false` on failure, hence the `$response === false` test. I used === in this case otherwise PHP may interpret an empty string as `false`, which doesn't make sense in this context.
- The network connection would fail unless I set the SSL version to 6 (or `CURL_SSLVERSION_TLSv1_2`)
- The API would forbid me from accessing the data unless I specified a believable user-agent, in this case Firefox.